# WPF referencing a text box text from another module, class or window

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have several named textboxes that contain values which I wish to save in a file. I used to be able to do this in winform by referencing the textbox from another module like this

```
owrite.Writeline(form1.textbox1.text)
```

Using WPF I am unable to figure how to do this. I can do it within the MainWindow.xaml.vb using this code

```
owrite.Writeline(me.textbox1.text)
```

But I cannot expose (find) the textbox when I try it from a different module. I could just do it from within the MainWindow, that is true, but I also would like to just know how.

EDIT:
Thank you for all assistance. As per some of the advise below I have used the following to create my settings document which essentially could be writen from any modules in the program. As I said it is not the correct way to code WPF and separate UI thread and data but for what it does it suits my purpose: (The Texts are named textboxes)

```
Dim mainWin = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of MainWindow).FirstOrDefault()

            Using oWrite As New System.IO.StreamWriter(AppPath & "\SETTINGS\User Config.txt", False)
                oWrite.WriteLine(mainWin.Text_ServerName.Text)
                oWrite.WriteLine(mainWin.Text_DBName.Text)
                oWrite.WriteLine(mainWin.Text_ServerUserName.Text)
                oWrite.WriteLine(mainWin.Text_ServerPass.Text)
                oWrite.WriteLine(mainWin.Text_StorageDriveLetter.Text)
                oWrite.Close()
            End Using
```

Comment: "try it from a different module." means different window?

Comment: Yes a different window could be one instance where this could apply. I however often create just code modules to organise my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the x:FieldModifier directive to change the modifier of the control field to be able to access it from any other class:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

**x:FieldModifier:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905(v=vs.110).aspx

Another option is to define a property in the code-behind class of the view and access the control through this property:

```
Class MainWindow
    Public ReadOnly Property TheTextBox() As TextBox
        Get
           Return textbox1
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

In both cases you will need to get a reference to the window before you can access any of its controls. You could for example use the Application.Current.Windows collection to get a reference to an open window:

```
Dim mainWindow As MainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of MainWindow).FirstOrDefault()
Dim s As String = mainWindow.TheTextBox.Text
```

Comment: As all I wanted to get the value in a routine that takes less then a second and is triggered by button click I just used the window reference. It may be not entirely in the spirit of the UI and data separation but it works effectively for my app. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As long as you named in the code behind you should be able to:

```
var data = MyTextBox.Text;

//Do whatever with your data.
```